# Getting error in student t-test using python

Tags: python

I would like to perform student t-test from the following two samples with null hypothesis as they have same mean:

$cat data1.txt

```
2
3
4
5
5
5
5
2
```

$cat data2.txt

```
4
7
9
10
8
7
3
```

I got the idea and a script to perform t-test from https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-code-the-students-t-test-from-scratch-in-python/

My script is:

$cat ttest.py

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import mean
from scipy.stats import sem
from scipy.stats import t
def independent_ttest(data1, data2, alpha):
        # calculate means
        mean1, mean2 = mean(data1), mean(data2)
        # calculate standard errors
        se1, se2 = sem(data1), sem(data2)
        # standard error on the difference between the samples
        sed = sqrt(se1**2.0 + se2**2.0)
        # calculate the t statistic
        t_stat = (mean1 - mean2) / sed
        # degrees of freedom
        df = len(data1) + len(data2) - 2
        # calculate the critical value
        cv = t.ppf(1.0 - alpha, df)
        # calculate the p-value
        p = (1.0 - t.cdf(abs(t_stat), df)) * 2.0
        # return everything
        return t_stat, df, cv, p
data1 = open('data1.txt')
data2 = open('data2.txt')
alpha = 0.05
t_stat, df, cv, p = independent_ttest(data1, data2, alpha)
print('t=%.3f, df=%d, cv=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (t_stat, df, cv, p))
# interpret via critical value
if abs(t_stat) <= cv:
        print('Accept null hypothesis that the means are equal.')
else:
        print('Reject the null hypothesis that the means are equal.')
# interpret via p-value
if p > alpha:
        print('Accept null hypothesis that the means are equal.')
else:
        print('Reject the null hypothesis that the means are equal.')
```

While I run this script as python3 ttest.py , I am getting following error. I think I need to change the print statement, but can't able to do it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t-test.py", line 28, in <module>
    t_stat, df, cv, p = independent_ttest(data1, data2, alpha)
  File "t-test.py", line 10, in independent_ttest
    mean1, mean2 = mean(data1), mean(data2)
  File "/home/kay/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3118, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kay/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 87, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount

  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int'
```

Comment: You cannot pass open file handle (`data1`) to `independent_ttest`. You must first read the data and convert it into a list of numbers.

Comment: And why don't you use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html?

Comment: @DYZ : Thanks. It worked perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 1):

So your issue is that you are opening the files but not reading the data from the file (or converting it to a list). Basically, opening a file just prepares the file to be read by Python - you need to read it separately.

Also as a quick sidenote, make sure to close the file when you are done or else you could run into issues if you run the code multiple times in quick succession. The code below should work for your needs, just replace the calls to open with this code, replacing file names and other details as needed. The array here is the data you are looking for to pass to `independent_ttest`.

```
array = []
with open("test1.txt") as file:
        while value:=file.readline():
                array.append(int(value))
print(array)
```

We open our file using `with` [to make sure it is closed at the end.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)
Then we use a while loop to read each line. The `:=` [assigns each line to value as they are looped through.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)
Finally, for each value we convert it from string to int and then append it to our list.

Hope this helped! Let me know if you have any questions!